# Extra Council Members bug?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Has anyone had an issue, appointing council members beyond the top 5?  There are extra positions, and when you go to appoint someone it says you don't have any honorary titles to give them.  Yet there are plenty.  When I go to give them an honorary title, like Kings Right Hand, they pop in there, then immediately disappear again.  Almost like they aren't eligible.

I'd like to fill my council full up, but can't see to figure out how.

Answer (score 3):

Are you a king or an emperor? According to the wiki article about the [council](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Council), kings and emperors get 1 and 2 "advisors", respectively, which are additional council members. I just created a kingdom and noticed the new advisor slot:

[image: Advisor]

Now I can appoint people to the council:

[image]

The tooltip seems to simply be misleading; presumably "advisor" is considered an honorary title and the tooltip is saying "no applicable (advisor) titles available", but the wording makes it seem like you need to assign one of the other honorary titles.